# Parsing ldap sid in node

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

Im trying to get all the groups of a user including nested groups, to make the query faster I'm trying to use the tokenGroups attribute so to not recursively query the groups of groups.

I got the tokenGroups with contains the sid of all the groups of the user.
The problem is entry.object gives me an array of weird string that I'm unable to use and object.raw gives me an array of jsons with type: "buffer" and data containing an array with numbers that I don't know what to do with.

Given what I have how do I parse the sid or get more info about each group?

Answer (score 3):

`tokenGroups` is a binary attribute, returned in a base64-encoded string. In order to use it in a query, you would need to decode it and convert to an escaped string, which [may be used in a query](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ObjectSID). To reduce the network load and increase performance, you may query all the groups in a single query and since `objectSid` is indexed, the result is blazing fast.

Let me give a command line example:

```
# Preparation

# Domain controller
$ ad_host=w2k8-dc.internal.local

# Get domain context automatically (or set manually)
$ base_dn=$(ldapsearch -LLL -Q -N -o ldif-wrap=no -h $ad_host -s base defaultNamingContext | grep '^defaultNamingContext:' | cut -f2- -d\ )
$ echo $base_dn
DC=internal,DC=local

# User to check
$ user=Administrator
$ user_dn=$(ldapsearch -LLL -Q -N -o ldif-wrap=no -h $ad_host -b "$base_dn" sAMAccountName=$user dn | grep '^dn:' | cut -f2- -d\ )
$ echo $user_dn
CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local

# Actual query

# Get token groups
$ token_groups=$(ldapsearch -LLL -Q -N -o ldif-wrap=no -h $ad_host -b "$user_dn" -s base tokenGroups | grep '^tokenGroups:' | cut -f2- -d\ )
$ echo $token_groups
AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAIQIAAA== AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAIAIAAA== AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAClus3m3pCzBhhoO3PAIAAA== AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAClus3m3pCzBhhoO3BgIAAA== AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAClus3m3pCzBhhoO3BwIAAA== AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAClus3m3pCzBhhoO3AQIAAA== AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAClus3m3pCzBhhoO3CAIAAA== AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAClus3m3pCzBhhoO3AAIAAA==

# Decode SIDs and prepare query
$ sid_query=$(for sid in $token_groups; do printf "(objectSid=%s)" $(echo $sid | base64 -d | hexdump -ve '"\\" /1 "%02x"'); done)
$ echo $sid_query
(objectSid=\01\02\00\00\00\00\00\05\20\00\00\00\21\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\02\00\00\00\00\00\05\20\00\00\00\20\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\0a\5b\ac\de\6d\e9\0b\30\61\86\83\b7\3c\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\0a\5b\ac\de\6d\e9\0b\30\61\86\83\b7\06\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\0a\5b\ac\de\6d\e9\0b\30\61\86\83\b7\07\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\0a\5b\ac\de\6d\e9\0b\30\61\86\83\b7\01\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\0a\5b\ac\de\6d\e9\0b\30\61\86\83\b7\08\02\00\00)(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\0a\5b\ac\de\6d\e9\0b\30\61\86\83\b7\00\02\00\00)

# Get group information
$ ldapsearch -LLL -Q -N -o ldif-wrap=no -h $ad_host -b "$base_dn" "(|$sid_query)" dn cn
dn: CN=Schema Admins,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Schema Admins

dn: CN=Enterprise Admins,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Enterprise Admins

dn: CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Administrators

dn: CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Users

dn: CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Domain Admins

dn: CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Domain Users

dn: CN=Group Policy Creator Owners,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Group Policy Creator Owners

dn: CN=Denied RODC Password Replication Group,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=local
cn: Denied RODC Password Replication Group
```

Note that using `tokenGroups` does not provide information about distribution groups. It includes however user's primary group (most probably `Domain Users`), which [is NOT included in `memberOf`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321360/how-to-use-native-adsi-components-to-find-the-primary-group) (nor the user is included in group's `member` attribute).

That would make a difference in results as the regular recursive `member` query will not return primary group nor the groups that a user would be a member through their primary group. For example, if user's primary group is `Domain Users`, and `Domain Users` is a member of group `my-security-group`, the latter will not be found through a
`member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:` query, but will be returned in `tokenGroups`.

Last but not least, `member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:` can be very expensive computationally and depending on domain's size, base DN and domain controller's load can take much time to resolve. For my real company's domain it is more or less 3 times longer than the SID query:

```
$ time ldapsearch -LLL -Q -N -o ldif-wrap=no -h $ad_host -b "$base_dn" "(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$user_dn))" dn | grep '^dn:' | wc -l
92

real    0m11.038s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.024s

$ time ldapsearch -LLL -Q -N -o ldif-wrap=no -h $ad_host -b "$base_dn" "(|$sid_query)" dn | grep '^dn:' | wc -l
111

real    0m2.851s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.033s
```

Note the difference in result count; the SID query returns some built-in groups and those groups that a user is member of through `Domain Users`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need help parsing the `tokenGroups`, then you'll have to show your code and what output you're actually getting.

But yes, `tokenGroups` gives you the SID of every *security* group that the user should be considered a member of (recursively). But there are caveats:

- If you want the name of each group, you have to look up the group based on the SID. That's basically one network request per group. If you want "faster", then this is bad. More network requests = slower.
- It will not include distribution groups (groups where the Group Type is "Distribution"). That may or may not matter to you.

My first question is always: Why do you want to know this? Do you really need to list every group the user is a member of? Or are you looking for one specific group. If you're looking for one group, then you can find the SID of that group and look for that SID in the `tokenGroups`.

If you really do want the name of every group, or you need to include distribution groups, then you're better off doing this differently. You can perform a search for all groups that have this user as a member:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=userDN))
```

Where `userDN` is the `distinguishedName` of the user. That weird looking number is the object identifier (OID) for `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`, which you can read more about on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax). Basically, it tells AD to do a recursive search. So it will return every group that has the user as a direct member, or nested member.

I wrote a couple articles on my website about this, which you might benefit from reading, especially if you have more than one domain in your environment. My code examples are C#, but it's really just LDAP in the background anyway, so the principles can be applied to any language.

- [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html)
- [Find out if one user is a member of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/09/13/one-user-is-member-of-a-group.html)